# How to remove the extra space from custom AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to make a custom AlertDialog. The issue is the extra space in the dialog (white rectangle at the pic). How to remove it?

[image: dialog]
here is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_alert_like_ui">

         <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/like_icon"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/likeIconId"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:padding="5dp" />

         <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/wowButtonId"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/love_icon"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button_for_round_menu_like_button"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

         <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:id="@+id/blehButtonId"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/bleh"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button_for_round_menu_like_button"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

         <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/dislikeButtonId"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/dislike_icon"
            android:background="@drawable/round_button_for_round_menu_like_button"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

in activity:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_for_long_like_button_option, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update the `layout_width` of your parent `LinearLayout` and the immediate child `LinearLayout` to **`match_parent`** instead of **`wrap_content`**. See the update code below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_alert_like_ui">

             <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/like_icon"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/likeIconId"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:padding="5dp"/>

             <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/wowButtonId"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/love_icon"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_button_for_round_menu_like_button"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

             <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:id="@+id/blehButtonId"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/bleh"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_button_for_round_menu_like_button"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

             <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/dislikeButtonId"
                android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/dislike_icon"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button_for_round_menu_like_button"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Update:

Try setting transparent background to your alert dialog after you called the `alertDialog.show()`.

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: i want to remove the white space( there will just be icon like facebook like button popup), rather than extending the layout to the alertdialog size.

Comment: @Imranrana07 got your point, I have updated my answer above, try it please

Comment: its just making background transparent. i am trying to make like facebook like button. if you can please help me

Comment: but your question was about removing that extra white background, please be specific about what you want and that's the only way we can help you

Comment: sorry, its a simple mistake, but i told you i want like facebook like button which popup just above the button.

Comment: @Imranrana07, I appreciate that you realise your problem. But you should understand that SO is not something where you can just ask I want this, after that someone will do that for you. You need to try for it yourself first, then ask help on specific problem. Like you did in the question, no one can give your desired solution based on the code you posted. There is no indication which button you are mentioning or from where you are using this layout. I would suggest you to post a new question with your attempts or edit this question enough so that someone can help you.

Comment: sourav, bro u r from bangladesh, i also from bd.if you dont mind may i be added with you on fb?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190806/discussion-between-sourav-bh-and-imranrana07).

Answer (score 0):

As an option, if you would create custom dialog, you can do like this:

```
  @Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Dialog dialog = getDialog();
    if (dialog != null) {
      int width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
      int height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
      dialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
    }
  }
```

Comment: then set background to transparent in theme to this dialog

Comment: i did not use theme

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout and customize. There is no need to nested linear layout. It causes performance problems.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="48dp"
              android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
              android:padding="4dp">

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/likeIconId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"/>

    <Space
            android:layout_width="8dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"/>

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/wowButtonId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"/>

    <Space
            android:layout_width="8dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"/>

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/blehButtonId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"/>

    <Space
            android:layout_width="8dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"/>

    <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/dislikeButtonId"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/black"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_delete"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And in activity or fragment you can call like this. There is no need to use alert dialog.

```
private fun showDialog(context: Context){
        val dialog = Dialog(context)
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout_for_long_like_button_option)
        dialog.show()
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your screen shot with this code? Because its working for me.

Comment: please check the pic

Comment: Did you use AlertDialog or normal dialog?

Comment: Please try my showDialog function. Do not use alert dialog.

Comment: what is val here?

Comment: İts kotlin code, in java Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);

Comment: o yes its working :). one more thing how to show it on the button i click?

Comment: In buttons onclick listener call showDialog method.

Comment: i could not understand you the ques. i want to show the dialog just above the button click

Comment: yes i know. actually i wanted to do like, there will just be icons like facebook like button popup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190828/discussion-between-imranrana07-and-toffor).

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys for your kind cooperation. i have solved my problem by myself. i just added a layout to the position i want and solved all. thank you again